# Mysql 8 keeps getting " SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' "

Tags: mysql

I keep getting the following error in Laravel application using **mysql version 8**.

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

To fix the error, I can do the following:

```
sudo mysql;

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'somepassword';
```

**But the problem is, this is happening every 5 months**

Is this due to user password expiration?

Please advise...

Comment: is [default_password_lifetime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_password_lifetime) set?

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/332139/my-mysql-command-line-client-password-keeps-changing-automatically-i-dont-use